# If $ x$ is an element of a group $G$ of order $40$. Prove that the centre of $G$ cannot have order $8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If you let G be a group and let x be an element of G. If G then has order 40, how can I go about proving that the centre of G cannot have order 8. I have an idea that the centralizer of G may help but I don't know how to approach the problem.

Comment: What is your $x$ doing?

Comment: The title is a little ambiguous about whether $x$ has order $40$ or $G$ has order $40$, but the body clearly states the hypothesis that $|G|=40$ (leaving the role of $x$ unaccounted for).

Answer (score 3):

This is a very weird question, as the role of $\;x\;$ is completely useless here. Anyway, try to prove that $\;G/Z(G)\;$ is cyclic iff $\;G\;$ is abelian, and in that case then it **must be** that $\;G/Z(G)=1\;$, or in other words: for **any group** $\;G\;$ , the quotient $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial.

Comment: $G$ is abelian if, and only if, $Z(G)=G$, so $G$ is abelian if, and only if, $G/Z(G)=\{e\}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes...though that is *not* the point I tried to make above.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose order of $Z(G)$ is 8,then order of $G/Z(G)=5$ i.e quotient group $G/Z(G)$ is a cyclic group which implies $G$ is abelian then order of $Z(G)$ will be $40$ i.e order of $G$ which is a contradiction.so order of $Z(G)$ never be $8$.
(Note:there is no role of the element $x$)